# Use variable name for diagram title

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How to use the variable name as a string for the title of the diagram in MATLAB

```
y = [11 22 33 44 55];

x = [1 2 3 4 5];

figure
plot (x,y)
title ('Diagram of ' x 'versus ' y);   % How to make this line work
```

The title should then read:

Diagram of x versus y

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure I understand your question. You *need* to know your variable names in order to create the plot, i.e. `plot(x, y)` forces you to enter `x` and `y` as variable names. Then what is the problem of just retyping that in the title:  `title('Diagram of x versus y');` If you don't know the variable name, you couldn't have created the plot in the first place

Comment: @Adriaan I can at least think of a use-case for debugging or rapid development, where you have some generic plotting code but you're chopping and changing what you're actually plotting, in which case it's easier to not have to maintain the link between variables used and the title.

Comment: I have many sets of data that I change at the beginning of the code depending on what I want to analyse. But then the code draws many diagrams throughout many lines. That is why I would like the title of the diagrams to be linked to the variable name, since that is what I am changing at the very beginning of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a helper function and use the `inputname` function

```
function tplot( varargin )
    plot(varargin{:})
    xname = inputname(1);
    yname = inputname(2);
    title( sprintf( 'Diagram of %s versus %s', xname, yname ) );
end
```

By using `varargin`, all normal functionality of `plot` will hold. However, this function assumes that the first two arguments are always the x and y data, which isn't strictly always the case for the normal `plot` function - to be handled as an edge case if required.

This can then be called using

```
y = [11 22 33 44 55];
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
figure
tplot(x,y); % titled plot
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I guess the edge case, i.e. only y-data to be plotted against its index, is easily checked for by confirming that both first and second input have conformant types and sizes. (Is there a case where you have 3 data points, no x-values, but do have an RGB triplet for colour? That might mess up your plot, but then again `plot()` would do that by default in that case)

Comment: @Adriaan yeah, unfortunately `plot` can take inputs _before_ x and y too (i.e. the axes handle), so there's a couple of random cases to handle, I'll leave this example simple but indeed it wouldn't be too taxing to put some `if` cases on the number of inputs within `varargin` and their size/type

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if I got your question correctly, but if the variable names always are x and y, just use one looong string:

```
('Diagram of  x versus  y')
```

Comment: If you're unsure whether you understood the question, it's usually better to refrain from answering and, when you have 50 reputation, comment to ask for clarification (see my comment), because your answer might be invalidated when the question turns out to be different from what you understood. That said, this indeed is the easiest solution (again, as per my comment), but completely ignores any possible programmatic aspect to automate this process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).